# Nodejs, Express getting request parameters at the beginning

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

I am building a web application, in which most requests to server, an identifier-data object mapping needs to be made. I want to override wherever a request is handled like this, but I do not want to write `mapping` to each request, is there a better way?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


function mapping(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.params); 
    // actual data fetch from server depending on req.params
    // Example, if req.params.userid defined -> fetch userid from db and place it
    if ( req.params.userid){
        req.user = {
            name: "Mustafa",
            title: "Student"
        }
    }
    next();
}

app.get("/:userid", mapping, function(req,res){
    res.send(req.user);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`app.param`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.param) to have the middleware apply specifically to routes where `userid` is present:

```
function mapping(req,res,next,userId){
    console.log(req.params); 
    // actual data fetch from server depending on req.params
    // Example, if req.params.userid defined -> fetch userid from db and place it
    if (userid){
        req.user = {
            name: "Mustafa",
            title: "Student"
        }
    }
    next();
}

app.param( "userid", mapping );

app.get("/:userid", function(req,res){
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. @go-oleg, I think you mistakenly left a redundant `mapping` on this line: `app.get("/:userid", mapping, function(req,res)`

Comment: @tuxedo25: Ah, oops, my b. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `app.use()` mapping. Since it always calls next(), it will defer to the next route once its work is finished.

```js
// always use 'mapping' middleware.
app.use(mapping);

// handle GET /{userid}
app.get("/:userid", function(req,res){
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

Comment: It does not work, because request first hits the app.use, but have no idea that my /15 is /:userid because it did not see /:userid first.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, and @go-oleg's answer is correct: you want to declare :userid as an `app.param`.